# Android insert image into DB

Tags: android

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying to insert an image into a database but its not working. Below is some of my code:

On click Code

```
public void click(View v){
        img= DatabaseHandler.getBytes(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.test));

         DatabaseHandler.insertFood("test","test",10.00,img);
         Toast toast =  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();

    }
```

DatabaseHandler Class

```
   public static long insertFood( String Name, String Description, Double Price,Byte[] Image ){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(nam,Name);
        cv.put(descrp, Description);
        cv.put(prc, Price);
        cv.put(img, Image);
        return sdb.insert(TABLE, null, cv);
    }
    public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
          ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
          return stream.toByteArray();
         }
```

The error
[image]

Image 2
  [image]

Comment: where is the lower case "price" / "description" coming from?  global constants? Also you need a String key for image.  You appear to be using lower case "image" as both key and value.

Comment: I just edited the first argument thats not their real name

Comment: well look at where you are putting image, you have the same variable twice.  The first one needs to be the string key, the second the byte array.

Comment: sorry but can you elaborate what you mean?

Comment: Your edit changed what I was trying to point out.  You had lower case image listed as both value and key.  A byte array cannot be a key for content values.

Comment: oh as i said the first image is not the real column name see edit

Comment: Could you extend the error stack trace to "Cause by: blabla" from your LogCat? The current LogCat doesn't really help.

Comment: @AndrewT. can you pls see the edit tnx!

Comment: Your database variable (sdb) is null.  That's the problem.  You need to post the code where your opening the database if you need further help.  p.s.  you'll run into null pointers and similar problems a ton, look on the logcat for the line that relates to code in your program (e.g. line 82 of DatabaseHandler), to find these errors.  just double click it, and it will take you right to that line.

Comment: @user3126670 i think you should put that as an answer im pretty stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP just needed to post a longer stack trace, to see he was trying to insert to a null database.  Credit to Andrew T. for asking user to post the longer trace.